# tracing error response on HttpInterceptor

Tags: angular

In my angular 6 application I am receiving error message from API, below is the code.

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler):Observable<HttpEvent<any>>{
 return next.handle(req)
 .pipe(
  catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse)=>{
   // const err="error occured"; 
   // console.log(error);
   // console.log(error.error.['@errors'].code);
   // console.log(`error log`, error.error.code)
    if (error.error['@errors'].code != 'ERR_UNITLIMIT') {
    this.MyService.errorHasOccurred(err);}
    return throwError(error);
   })
 );
 }
```

I am getting below response from  service like below

```
{"@errors":[{"code":"ERR_UNITLIMIT","message":"total cart value must not be exceed 500$.","details":[]}],"@warnings":[]}
```

I am trying to check if response object code contains ERR_UNITLIMIT or not . I tried things which has been commented in above code using **//** but always getting error of code is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since "@errors" is an array of objects , you have to refer it using the index 0.
`console.log(error.error['@errors'][0].code)` will do the job.

change your function as below

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler):Observable<HttpEvent<any>>{
 return next.handle(req)
 .pipe(
  catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse)=>{
    if (error.error['@errors'][0].code != 'ERR_UNITLIMIT') {
    this.MyService.errorHasOccurred(error);}
    return throwError(error);
   })
 );
 }
```

Comment: I cant it seems, because of mine low points, you could upvote question as well :)

Comment: there is a tick symbol near my answer you can click on it.

Comment: if(error.error){
    if(error.error['@errors'][0]){
    if (error.error['@errors'][0].code != 'ERR_PR_UNITLIMIT') {

Comment: Try error['@errors'][0] instead of error.error['@errors'][0]

Comment: No I tried that way only, please see my comment I am already having check on that

Comment: please see my initial post, I will not received same object every time

Comment: if the  structure is as in your question :error['@errors'][0] will work